# Management of JS static files: code seems to be downloaded but do not work

Tags: javascript, python, django, static-libraries

I have a Django project with 2 apps: registration and randomization

```
- django-project
   - registration
   - randomization
     - static
        - randomization
           - js
               - script.js
     - templates
        - randomization
           - stock.html
   - templates
     - layouts
        - _nav.html
        - base.html
     - home.html
```

I use JQuery/ajax that work but is repeated in all my templates so I want to refactor

script.js seems to be download (browser debug network / status = 200)
but when I run my ajax request, I got the following error:

> Not Found: /{% url "randomization:stock" %}

I try to manage static files like this:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
)
```

**randomization/static/randomization/js/script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //CORRECTION
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    //END CORRECTION

    $("#site").on("change", function(event){

        console.log($(this).val());
        //CORRECTION
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: '{% url "randomization:stock" %}',
            url: $("#site").data("randomization-url"), //CORRECTION
            data: {
                //csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',//CORRECTION
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'site' : $(this).val(), 
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.includes("Insufficient")) {
                    $("#alerte").html(data);
                    $("#randomize").children().remove();
                }
                else {
                    $("#alerte").children().remove();
                    $("#randomize").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });


    $("body")
    .on("click", '#informations', function(event) {
        $('#pharmacy').modal('show');
    })

    .on('click','#button_ok',function(event){
        $(this).modal('close')
    });

});
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">


{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'layouts/_nav.html' %}     
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% include 'randomization/_alerte.html' %}
    {% include 'layouts/_footer.html' %}
    <!--09/11/2019 : config qui fonctionne-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--09/11/2019 : config qui fonctionne-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'randomization/js/script.js' %}"></script>   
    {% block extrabody %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

page.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}{% trans 'Homepage' %} | Intense TBM{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class='container'>
<h1>page.html</h1>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the template tags within Django templates. The static files are simply files that are served as is by typically the web server (apache, nginx) or served by a CDN.

What you can do is something like this:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#site").on("change", function(event){

    console.log($(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#site").data("randomization-url"),
        ...
```

Then in the template that defines the html tag with id "site", you'd do the following:

```
<div id="site" data-randomization-url="{% url 'randomization:stock' %}"></div>
```

This way your element defines the URL that should be used and you don't have to worry about any weirdness being injected into your javascript. And you don't have to resort to hardcoding url paths in your javascript.

Comment: thanks ! I have just understand tags can not be use in .js ; I will have the same problem with {{ crsf_token }}

Comment: Django has you covered: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax